# TCP Hole Punching Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, hole-punching

I am going to make a peer 2 peer Application, I am newbie in programming, I read some articles about hole punching, now I have a basic concept of NAT and hole punching technique. but in practical I couldn't succeed to do it.
I am going to make use of hole punching technique, and i have make this simple test application in C# Which sends a request to PHP server to find the public IP and PORT, after achieving IP and Port It sends a Request to this achieved IP(loop back), but it does not work.
I don't know Why it does not work, Where am I doing wrong?
Here is my Code.

```
class Program
{
    static EndPoint myPublicAddress;
    Socket stunClient;
    IPEndPoint stunServer = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostAddresses("ultrarate.tech")[0], 80);
    Socket listener;
    EndPoint localEndpoint;
    String stunRequestPacket = "GET http://ultrarate.tech/test/stun.php HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0\nHost: 10.154.90.59:4030\nConnection: close\n\n";

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.go();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public void go() {
        stunClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.154.90.59"),4030);
        try
        {
            stunClient.Bind(localEndpoint);
            stunClient.Connect(stunServer);
            Console.WriteLine("MainThread:__ Your Private IP and Port:-  " + stunClient.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine("MainThread:__ Requesting your public IP and Port....\n\n\n");
            stunClient.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stunRequestPacket));
            int x = stunClient.Receive(buffer);
            string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, x);

            string ip = response.Substring(response.IndexOf("<ip>") + 4,
                                           response.IndexOf("</ip>") - response.IndexOf("<ip>") - 4);

            int port = Convert.ToInt32(response.Substring(
                                                            response.IndexOf("<port>") + 6,
                                                            response.IndexOf("</port>") - response.IndexOf("<port>") - 6
                                                          )
                                       );

            Console.WriteLine("MainThread:__ Your Public IP and Port is:-   " + ip + ":" + port + "\n\n");
            myPublicAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
            stunClient.Disconnect(false);
            stunClient.Close();
            stunClient.Dispose();
            stunClient = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listener.Bind(localEndpoint);
        listener.Listen(10);
        Console.WriteLine("MainThread:__ Listening On\t" + localEndpoint.ToString() + "\n\n\n");
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(makeRequest);
        Thread t = new Thread(ts);
        t.Start();
        Socket ns = listener.Accept();
        Console.WriteLine("MainThread:__ Connection Recieved:"+ns.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
        int count = ns.Receive(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine("MainThread:__ Message Recieved:" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, count));

        listener.Close();
        listener.Dispose();
    }
    static void makeRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            Socket newSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Console.WriteLine("\tThread 2:__ Loopback Request to Public Addr (" + myPublicAddress.ToString() + ")");
            newSock.Connect(myPublicAddress);
            newSock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello i am from outSide"));
            newSock.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\nThread 2:__ "+ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my PHP file.

```
<?php 
     echo "<result>";
     echo "<ip>".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."</ip>";
     echo "<port>".$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']."</port>";
     echo "</result>";
?>
```

When I run the application, The out put is like This

[image: Application Output ScreenShot]

Comment: STUN only works for UDP. STUNT is the variant for TCP. It's unreliable, more complicated than this, and just plain cannot work with some routers.

Comment: Please do not post text as image.  Post text as text.  Thanks.